EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Init with Escaping Closure
I am trying to initialize a class with an escaping closure inside my unit test, but it always crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). Here my code for declaring the class:
public class ListMock<T: HashDiffable & Equatable>: UICollectionView {
    private let content: (T) -> UICollectionViewCell
    
    public init(
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout(),
        content: @escaping (T) -> UICollectionViewCell
    ) {
        self.content = content
        super.init(
            frame: .zero,
            collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout
        )
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

And here how I initialize ListMock inside my unit test functions:
internal final class ListTests: XCTestCase {
    internal func testInitList() {
        let listNode = ListMock<ListNodeTestModel> { model in
            model.generateListCellNode()
        }
    }
}

internal struct ListNodeTestModel: Equatable, HashDiffable {
    internal let id: Int
    internal var desc: String = ""

    internal static func == (lhs: ListNodeTestModel, rhs: ListNodeTestModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.desc == rhs.desc
    }

    internal func generateListCellNode() -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}

After some debugging, I found that the culprit is HashDiffable protocol:
public protocol HashDiffable {
    associatedtype IdentifierType: Hashable
    var id: Self.IdentifierType { get }
    func isEqual(to source: Self) -> Bool
}

public extension HashDiffable where Self: Hashable {
    /// The `self` value as an identifier for difference calculation.
    var id: Self {
        return self
    }
}

extension HashDiffable where Self: Equatable {
    public func isEqual(to source: Self) -> Bool {
        return self == source
    }
}

But I am still not sure, why this protocol trigger this crash. I also try to add Sendable conformance to ListMock generic, but it still return EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
Swift 5.9
Xcode 15.4

What is your crashing test exactly?  ListTests().testInitList() doesn't crash for me, and I think it's due to more complex tests...

I am testing some methods and adding assertions to some properties that I expect to change (Not a complex test case). I comment on all my assertions and leave the listNode init uncommented. And it still gave me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when I tested my module (cmd+U).
HashDiffable is on different package

You test the whole module, but testing only the testFunction where there is an init still give you the issue? Could you reproduce it in a new project with only that?

I can't reproduce it in the fresh project. And it weirdly solved by moving List related object and its tests to the same module as HashDiffable
